# How to compute variances from a matrix/table

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have created a matrix/table with an imported dataset. I want to know what the variance is for 3 values at a time but across 68 columns. I would like to do this in an automated way rather than 1 set of values at a time. Is there a way?

I'm new to Mathematica, so if there is a really simple way, I don't know about it yet!

Comment: If your data is stored in `data`, what does `Dimensions[data]` say?

Comment: Check the second example in the `Basic Examples` section of [`Variance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Variance.html) in the docs.

Comment: An example dataset with the desired outcome would be helpful here.